# Connect Cloudant Bluemix with SPSS

Tags: ibm-cloud, spss, cloudant, spss-modeler

I'm trying to connect Cloudant Database from Bluemix to SPSS modeler, following a tutorial from [here](http://blog.armandruiz.com/2014/09/30/mining-cloud-data-with-spss-direct-connection-of-cloudant-to-bluemix/) but what I get is the error message [image]

Anyone can help me? 
Here is my model followed the tutorial [image]